# chat socket (web socket)is closing unexpectedly (django-channels)?

Tags: django, django-channels, channel

[console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lghc.png)

i have gone through as it mentioned in the docs(channels) it worked fine until i pasted the code of channel_layers in settings.py

i installed all the specifications mentioned in channel_layers

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.routing.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

why is my chat_server closing unexpectedly

Comment: Is redis running on that port locally?

Comment: thanks, it was working fine now. i messed up a lot of  my code and fixed it.

Comment: You can post an answer on how you solved it. It could potentially help another person

Answer (score 1):

First of all check wheather redis is running in your machine or not.

if not google it you will find.

->check these points wheather you had done correctly:

1.check wheather the data you send to sockets are in string format.

2.check the json you are sending to sockets is correctly parsed.

3.similarly check the data received from sockets is correctly parsed.

> if you want to automatically reconnect to sockets use 
>    https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket copy the js file there  and place the script in your html and then replace WebSocket to ReconnectingWebSocket

Answer (score 1):

This problem arise due to reddis channel not working at backend after configuring in the setting.py you should start the reddis channel

if you are using docker then try this

docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis:5

Comment: How can I start without using docker?

Comment: sudo systemctl restart redis.service
sudo systemctl status redis

Answer (score 1):

if u have connections problem with django-channels,

first install channels -->  pip install -U channels
after installing channels add 'channels' install app in your setting.py file and follow these docs to install channels properly in your django project
--> https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

after installing django channels now install channels-redis in your django project,

> first step is to install redis in your local machine , but install redis 5 or above
> follow installing steps to install redis server in ubuntu and download redis direct if you use windows.
> download plus installing steps in this link--> https://redis.io/download

after istalling redis in your local machine install channels-redis in your django project
--> pip install channels-redis==2.4.2

this is latest solution of django channels connection problem with redis , i hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem .

My websocket connect and disconnect immediately ,

Although Redis was installed,

The problem was with the Redis version.

Your Redis version must be greater than five